# selenium ERROR :policy_loader_win.cc

Tags: python, selenium

I encounter an ERROR when I use selenium to login a website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/ProgramFiles/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://bbs.pinggu.org/member.php?mod=logging&action=login")
login_name=driver.find_element_by_name("username")
login_name.clear()
login_name.send_keys("")  ##this is login name. omit
login_name.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
login_pass=driver.find_element_by_name("password")
login_pass.clear()
login_pass.send_keys("")   ##this is login password. omit
login_pass.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

login=driver.find_element_by_name('loginsubmit')
login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.close()
```

I get an ERROR:

```
[9492:8552:0918/152646:ERROR:policy_loader_win.cc(449)]PReg file doesn't exist:C:\WINDOWS\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Registry.pol
```

I search some item, but I don't know to use it.

https://gitlab.com/fancycode/iridium-browser/blob/75a646c6596597e9c21659187fe75bbd68c2c2b9/components/policy/core/common/policy_loader_win.cc

Comment: I use code of the link, but it won't work.